# What can be a better way to modify this code[refactoring]

Tags: java, refactoring

Is there a better way to present this code?

```
while (vIter.hasNext()) {
    Long actId = (Long) vIter.next();
    if (actId == -1) 
        vRetActIds.put(actId,"N");
    else
        vRetActIds.put(actId,"N");
}
```

Here I feel the `if else` can be made redundant. In the iterator list there is a value `-1` which if exists should be made `"N"`.

Comment: while (vIter.hasNext()) vRetActIds.put((Long)vIter.next(),"N");

Comment: from the code i see, both if and else part are same. Any typo?

Comment: You can declare your collection `Collection<Long>`, get an `Iterator<Long>` and avoid the cast.

Comment: you are placing same value in both if and else condition. correct it!!

Comment: yes indeed its correct,I get a set of actIds from DB and irrespetive of the value of actId =-1, I need to set it 'N' and others actIds I have to explicitly set to 'N'

Comment: ? You're setting the value to 'N' every time? Why bother with the if (actId == -1) at all then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two instructions are the same on both sides of the if! I suspect you pasted something wrong. Let's assume they're different (`"Y"` and `"N"`) :) You can write it simply using the [ternary operator](http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/ternary.html):

```
while (vIter.hasNext()) {
    Long actId =(Long)vIter.next();
    vRetActIds.put(actId, actId == -1 ? "N" : "Y");
}
```

**EDIT:** From your comments, it seems like you actually want to set the value to 'N' every time? In that case, you don't need the `if` at all...

```
while (vIter.hasNext()) {
    vRetActIds.put((Long)vIter.next(), "N");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that you are using a Collection of some sort in the new java, something like this would be more concise and won't crash due to null pointers?

```
Long MINUS_ONE = Long.valueOf(-1);
while (Long actId : vIter) 
{
    vRetActIds.put(actId, MINUS_ONE.equals(actiId) ? "N" : "Y");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary conditional statement would be fine.

```
vRetActIds.put(actId, actiId == -1 ? "N" : "Y");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're getting your iterator from somewhere like a List:

```
List<Long> list;
Iterator<Long> vIter = list.iterator();
```

If that's the case (and it, or something like it, almost has to be the case), then you can forgo the iterator entirely and make your code much easier to read, thus:

```
for (Long actId: list)
    vRetActIds.put(actId, "N");
```